# Concrete bonding adhesive and concrete cleaner with hydraulic cement?

Tags: concrete, repair, cement

I'm planning to use hydraulic cement to fill a few small holes in my foundation. Neither is actively leaking water at this time, but are very slightly damp.

When using hydraulic cement, is there any advantage or disadvantage to prepping the area with concrete bonding adhesive, i.e. the stuff that's recommended for priming the face of the old concrete before applying new concrete or vinyl patch concretes?

What about cleaning the area with concrete cleaners?

I know hydraulic cement is a little different from regular stuff in terms of how it sets and bonds, so I don't want to mess up the bonding interface. From tutorials I've seen online, I haven't seen anyone talk about using bonding adhesive with it.

Specific product examples of the above are QUIKRETE Hydraulic Water-Stop Cement, QUIKRETE Concrete and Asphalt Cleaner, and QUIKRETE Concrete Bonding Adhesive.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're interested in the interactions between 3 QUIKRETE products have you tried contacting them?

Comment: @RetiredATC No, I haven't but that's a good point. I'll reach out to them as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hydraulic cement usually calls for making a keyway/make the opening larger inside than the outside opening to lock in.  Whenever adding/bonding to any surface cleaning is first thing to do.   The bonding adhesive is probably not needed if the instructions are followed.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, the inverted 'V' shape people talk about. I'm aware of that, and plan to do do so. I was just trying to figure out if primer would add any additional benefit. I've reached out to Quikrete as well and will report back if they have any insight.

Comment: Believe the primer/adhesive is more for resurfacing a flat floor/wall with a similar cement/concrete.  The hydraulic cement is more for small holes/cracks that can use the inverted V for better locking/bonding.  Think the hydraulic cement has a slight expansion size when drying.